# Creating a Generic Save() Method for Models

Tags: c#, generics, repository

I have a fairly simple system, and for the purposes of this question there are essentially three parts:  Models, Repositories, Application Code.

At the core are the models.  Let's use a simple contrived example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

In that same project is a generic repository interface.  At its simplest:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Save(T model);
}
```

Implementations of that interface are in a separate project and injected with StructureMap.  For simplicity:

```
public class PersonRepository : IRepository<Person>
{
    public Person Save(Person model)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("I got to the save method!");
        // In the repository methods I would interact with the database, or
        // potentially with some other service for data persistence.  For
        // now I'm just using LINQ to SQL to a single database, but in the
        // future there will be more databases, external services, etc. all
        // abstracted behind here.
    }
}
```

So, in application code, if I wanted to save a model I would do this:

```
var rep = IoCFactory.Current.Container.GetInstance<IRepository<Person>>();
myPerson = rep.Save(myPerson);
```

Simple enough, but it feels like it could be automated a lot.  That pattern holds throughout the application code, so what I'm looking to do is create a single generic `Save()` on all models which would just be a shorthand call to the above application code.  That way one would need only call:

```
myPerson.Save();
```

But I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.  Maybe it's deceptively simple and I'm just not looking at it from the correct angle.  At first I tried creating an empty `ISaveableModel<T>` interface and intended to have each "save-able" model implement it, then for the single generic `Save()` method I would have an extension on the interface:

```
public static void Save<T>(this ISaveableModel<T> model)
{
    var rep = IoCFactory.Current.Container.GetInstance<IRepository<T>>();
    model = rep.Save(model);
}
```

But it tells me that `rep.Save(model)` has invalid arguments.  It seems that it's not wiring up the type inference as I'd hoped it would.  I tried a similar approach with a `BaseModel<T>` class from which models would inherit:

```
public class BaseModel<T>
{
    public void Save()
    {
        this = IoCFactory.Current.Container.GetInstance<IRepository<T>>().Save(this);
    }
}
```

But the compiler error is the same.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?  I'm very flexible on the design, so if I'm going about something all wrong on an architectural level then I have room to step back and change the big picture.

Comment: What Data Library are you using? Linq To SQL? Entities?

Comment: In your example, `BaseModel<T>` does not implement `ISaveableModel<T>`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Oliver: Currently I'm using LINQ to SQL in the repository implementations for simplicity, but that really shouldn't matter in this design where all data access is abstracted behind repository interfaces, should it?  An overarching goal is to keep all data access code strictly out of the core domain project.  I've yet to find an ORM that does that very well (though I could just be using them wrong).

Comment: @agent-j: Well, I figured the two were logically mutually exclusive in this case.  If one works, there's no reason to have the other.  I'd rather do this with interfaces than with inheritance, but if I have to use inheritance then the interface is empty and the extension method goes away, so there wouldn't be an interface.

Comment: I wrote generic Linq to SQL insert and delete methods, I wrote a generic update method that updates all the properties of an edited object.  The last example (update), I use when the object is unbound from the data context, eg, deserialised from a http post.  Will any of these methods help? I also wrote a generic method that will update an entire entity collection (all edited fields, insert new entities, delete missing entities) if this will be any use.

Comment: @Oliver: I suppose that could help, it's tough to say without seeing it.  Keep in mind that the Models in this setup are strictly code.  They have no relation to any data persistence and no LINQ data context to use.  These are not auto-generated from a database or anything of the sort.  Basically, they're not database entities.  They're strictly domain models.

Comment: They might work with a bit of editing.  I would recommend using Reflection to loop through the fields in your typed object.  I don't have them here, I'll post them later.

Comment: Just looking around on here, I found this which is similar to my update method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923196/generic-edit-in-repository

Comment: @Oliver: I'm not seeing how using reflection to loop through the object's members has any bearing on this.  Would I be looping through my Models to compare them with the reflected members to determine the type of the object for the method call?  That definitely sounds like overkill and I don't think would be worth the trade-off of saving the chore of the example application code.

Comment: @Oliver: That looks like it would be used within the repository methods, where the data context is available.  That's not really the route I'm trying to take, because each repository may have different persistence logic rather than one generic method.  What I'm looking to do is make a generic domain method for wiring up the correct repository call with the correct model type.  Once I'm inside the repository methods, I'm fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would a generic extension method solve it?

```
public static T Save<T>(this T current)
{
    var rep = IoCFactory.Current.Container.GetInstance<IRepository<T>>();
    rep.Save(current);
}
```

You can then constrain it to your `ISaveableModel<T>` interface. Return type above not implemented, but you can put it to a boolean or status flag, whatever.

Comment: Yup, looks like this was a good direction to go.  I've added a `where` clause on the extension method as well to prevent it from being called on any object in the system, only on ones that implement the given interface.  Seems to be working fine so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In both approaches, the parameter to the `Save()` function is not of type `T`. In the first one, it is `ISaveableModel<T>`, and in the second, it is `BaseModel<T>`. Since the repository is a generic based on `T`, `Save` method will expect a variable of type `T`. You can add a simple cast to `T` before you call `Save` to fix it.

Alternatively, your `IRepostory<T>` can be changed to

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    T Save(ISaveableModel<T> model);
}
```

which makes more sense.